# File input not working when clicked

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

This is my first time using foundation coming from bootstrap(a noob) i created a file input button

```
<label>Upload songs/images
    <label for="song" class="button small-12 hollow">Upload File</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleFileUpload" class="show-for-sr">
</label>
```

but when i click on it nothing happens what would be the problem?

```html
<label>Upload songs/images
        <label for="song" class="button small-12 hollow">Upload File</label>
<input type="file" id="exampleFileUpload" class="show-for-sr">
</label>
```

Comment: It must work, I checked your code. What are you expecting to happen ?

Comment: the pop up window to select files to appear

Comment: but it is appearing, wait let me edit your OP

Comment: See your code is working ;)

Comment: i see here is working but it doesnt in my browser with the button i dont know why but it isnt

Comment: I dont know why but when changing label `for` to something else than what the example at foundation page show it stops working